# How can I parse a string with unicode characters in lark-parser in python

Tags: python, lark-parser

I'm trying to use lark parser in Python to parse some sql strings. Some of the statements have unicode characters in them, causing the parser to throw error (strings with ó,é).
I'm using the following lines to define strings in my .lark file

```
LATIN_LETTER: /[u"\u00a1-\u02af"]/
STRING: (LATIN_LETTER|LETTER|DIGIT|PUNCTUATION)+
```

Error thrown

```
E   UnexpectedCharacters: No terminal defined for '�' at line 154 col 126
E   
E   jillo', 'Owner', 'Avda. de la Constitución 2222', 'México D.F.', NULL, '05021'
```

Am I specifying the unicode letters incorrectly in the .lark file? What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
LATIN_LETTER: /[u"\u00a1-\u02af"]/
```

to

```
LATIN_LETTER: ("¡".."ʯ")
```

worked

Answer (score -1):

```
CHINESE_LETTER: ("\u4e00".."\u9fff") | ("\u3000".."\u303f")
```